# divide long and converting to a double in JAVA

Tags: java

Having this piece of code

```
System.out.println (routeSummary);

long ms = (Long)routeSummary.get("total_distance");

System.out.println (ms);

double kms = (ms / 1000);

System.out.println (kms);
```

`ms = 19283`  but `kms = 19.0` ??? shouldn't be `19.283` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
double kms = (ms / 1000.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to typecast the variables. Dividing two long's would result into a long. You could use this:

```
double kms = (double)ms / 1000.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `double kms = (ms / 1000);` with

```
double kms = (ms / 1000.00);
```

**reason** ms is long and 1000 is int so when you divide,decimal part will be truncated
so either make 1000.00 or 1000.0 or 1000.000 cast it double like (Double)1000

[output](https://ideone.com/4unzdM)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure one of the variables you are calculating with has the desired outcome type, at least a floating point.

```
double kms = ((double) ms / 1000);
```

or

```
double kms = ( ms / (double) 1000);
```

or

```
double t = 1000;
double kms = ms / t;
```